# View Model Null when not explicitly passed by controller to strongly typed view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

my view is defined

```
    @model BloombergGUI.Models.SecurityViewAltModel

    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextArea("TestArea",Model.FieldsList)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.FieldsList, new {@class = "form-control"})
    </div>
```

if the controller for this strongly typed view is defined as

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();  //The first Html.TextArea says Model.FieldList is null
    }
```

if it's defined as the following, then both statements in the view work.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new SecurityViewAltModel());
    }
```

Why when the view is strongly typed is Model.Property indicating Model is null but when I explicitly pass a new model() then Model.Property works fine.  I thought Model was just another way of accessing the strongly typed model for the view and m=> m.property was a lambda expression for the TextBoxFor extension method used on strongly typed views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
@model BloombergGUI.Models.SecurityViewAltModel
```

you define in the View is actually a strongly typed **data passing** mechanism from the controller.

when you do

```
 return View();
```

you should be getting a NULL Model. This is because no data is being passed to the View. Model is expected to be null.

when you do

```
return View(new SecurityViewAltModel());
```

a non-null Model object is sent with all fields null. MVC will render empty controls for these null data fields.

**Note** that in the second case, you might not get the Null reference exception because you're not dealing with a straight object.field reference, but an **Expression**.

`m => m.FieldsList` vs. `Model.FieldsList`

**Details:**

1. When the expression is being evaluated, there can be checks which will prevent the null reference.
2. Deep inside the MVC DLLs, when the Expression is being processed, it has logic as follows:
3. Evaluate the Value of the **Expression** with Parameter as **viewData.Model** object.

The call is as follows:

**`CachedExpressionCompiler.Process<TParameter, TValue>(expression)(model);`**

And at that time, it goes into the **FingerprintingExpressionVisitor** and it can handle the null Model and returns null response for the Extension helper to not render any data.

Comment: To both who answered the question... if return View() passes a null model back to the view, why then does the second textboxfor still render. The page renders fine if I take out @Html.TextArea("TestArea",Model.FieldsList). If Model is null wouldn't m=>m.FieldsList fail as well

Comment: thats because there is a difference.. edited my anser

Comment: When I tried to execute the CachedExpressionCompiler.Process<TParameter, TValue>(expression)(model); line in the immediate window during debugging with a break point set on the TextBoxFor line, it indicated " The name 'CachedExpressionCompiler' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: that is an internal MVC DLL call. you cannot call it. i am merely explaining the details of why the null model object doesn't throw the exception. When it evaluates the m.Fields expression, it walks up the expression and finds that m itself is null. so the expression is evaulated to return null

Comment: AH! Ok, sorry for the misinterpretation. Thanks!